# ModalDialog: HTML-Table should be scrollable, not the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, showmodaldialog

I have a page with a header and a footer (both divs) and a table. I want the table to use the full required width and to show a scrollbar, if required. The scrollbar should only be visible for the table, not the whole page (header/ footer should be fixed). See the following example, which perfectly works:

[JSFiddle - Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8s8yd9t9/)

The same code doesn't work, if the page is shown by a call to `window.showModalDialog`.
The header/ footer doesn't use the full width in this case (even if width is set to 100%) and the scrollbar is shown for the full page. The table doesn't use the required width either. What's the difference when the page is loaded in a modal dialog?

***Edit:*** I need to use ModalDialog because I need the website to stop and wait for the dialog result.

Answer (score 0):

Review the varOptions parameter and the option:

```
scroll:{ yes | no | 1 | 0 | on | off }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx